# Independent event probability

Tags: probability

Quoted from a popular book,

> For instance, if we flip a fair coin twice, knowing whether the first
>   flip is Heads gives us no information about whether the second flip is
>   Heads. These events are independent.
>
> On the other hand, knowing whether the first flip is Heads certainly
>   gives us information about whether both flips are Tails. (If the first
>   flip is Heads, then definitely it’s not the case that both flips are
>   Tails.) These two events are dependent.
>
> Mathematically, we say that two events E and F are independent if the
>   probability that they both happen is the product of the probabilities
>   that each one happens:
>
> ```
> P(E,F) = P(E)P(F)
> ```
>
> In the example above, the probability of “first flip Heads” is 1/2,
>   and the probability of “both flips Tails” is 1/4, but the probability
>   of “first flip Heads and both flips Tails” is 0.

QUESTION: In the example we say

```
P(first flip Heads) = 1/2
P(both flips Tails) = 1/4
P(first flip Heads and both flips Tails) = 1/2 * 1/4 (WHY NOT THIS?)
P(first flip Heads and both flips Tails) = 0 (CORRECT ANSWER)
```

Although it makes logical sense to put zero, but doesn't explain why doesn't it fit the formula

Comment: The formula doesn't apply because of course these events aren't independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the expression a little bit.

When we say both flip heads, we are referring to
$$P(H_1,H_2)=P(H_1)P(H_2)$$
which we can directly apply the formula.

But when we take it one step further with "first flip head and both flip tails" we are finding

$$P(H_1\wedge(T_1\wedge T_2))$$

for now the 'terms' $H_1$ and $(T_1\wedge T_2)$ are not independent since we are talking about the same first coin which can only show one side. But we can rewrite the expression to
$$P((H_1\wedge T_1)\wedge T_2))$$
which makes the same combinatorial sense, but the two 'terms' are now independent so we can evaluate
$$P((H_1\wedge T_1)\wedge T_2))=P(H_1\wedge T_1)P( T_2)$$
and clearly
$$P(H_1\wedge T_1)=0$$
I hope this explains :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it explained the situation flawlessly. I won't ever forget this.

Answer (score 2):

You have already given yourself the answer.

The events $TT$ and $H\cdot$ **are dependent**. Independence of two events $E,F$ would mean that

- $P(E|F)= \frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)}= P(E)$.

But in your case you have
$$P(TT | H\cdot) = 0 \neq P(TT)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's say event $E$ is first flip Heads and event $F$ is both flips Tails.

\begin{align*}
  P(E) &= 1/2 \\
  P(F) &= 1/4 \\
  P(E,F) &= 0 \\
  P(E,F) &\neq P(E) \cdot P(F) \\
\end{align*}

It doesn't fit the formula for independence because the two events are not independent.